# Server connection lost polling for restart in shopify cli when do hosted in heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, shopify, vite

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import "dotenv/config";

/**
 * @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
 */
export default {
  define: {
    "process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY": JSON.stringify(process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY),
  },
  server: {
    hmr: {
      clientPort: 8080,
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
};
```

error like this comming - ​ WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:64999/' failed:  -- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () --
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
[vite] server connection lost. polling for restart...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?